# How do I change the directories that the left menu direct to in the GNOME file browser?

Tags: gnome

Some months ago I ran a shell script that I found on Github that was supposed to integrate OneDrive syncing into GNOME. However, as a consequence of this, the buttons in the left column of the file browser now redirect to ~/OneDrive/Desktop or whatever, instead of the ~/Desktop folder.

[image: Screenshot of the file browser column I am referring to]

I can't find the script I originally ran, and so I can't track back to what command made this happen to begin with. I am trying to figure out how to redirect these buttons to the correct folders (~/Desktop, not ~/OneDrive/Desktop). It's very annoying; does anyone know how this can be repaired?

I am running GNOME version 3.36.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64-bit.

Comment: Hey BetterOffHangingOutWithABunchO! Is this the script which you used: https://gist.github.com/glmdev/6ab5bbdfde5da3b065eba3fb38f91c24?

Comment: Hi Random Person - matter of fact, I think it was.

Answer (score 0):

Find and open the `.config/user-dirs.dirs` file under your home folder in a text editor. The script will have changed the assignment of the special "Desktop" folder. Make sure the line for XDG_DESKTOP reads like: `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"`. That will restore the default behaviour of the "Desktop" button.

Comment: Thanks - I think something like this worked!

Comment: @BetterOffHangingOutWithABunchO Please go through this help center article: https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers. BTW, I suggest you to go through the [tour] page.